# Cannot Find the file in internal storage of real device in android

Tags: android, file-io

This is the Code I am trying to create a file in internal storage in android. It is working in emulator and I can see the file in data/data/packagename/  but in real device I could not find this file.
**To be More Clear I cannot find the path data/data/peckagename/ in real device and did not see any file name data.txt. I want to export it too using eclipse or any other application**

```
File mydir = this.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
    File    heapFile = new File(mydir, "data.txt"); 
     FileWriter heapFileWritter = null;
     String file="";
    try{
        if (!heapFile.exists()) {

             heapFile.createNewFile();

        }
         file = heapFile.getAbsolutePath();
           heapFileWritter = new FileWriter(file);

           heapFileWritter.write(MyService.callcount);
```

Comment: Do you have any logcat output ?

Comment: It did not gives any Error in logcat.

Comment: How are you attempting to see a file which is hidden from the user on the internal storage? Write some code to re-test if it exits after creating.

Comment: it is created i checked that but cannot see in File Explorer.

Comment: Like I said, it is hidden from the user. Only the device can see the file. Unless your phone is rooted. If you are wanting to export it in eclipse, save it to the "external" storage, so that you have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could see only files in external storage, you could not see files in internal storage of your device except you rooted or installed an application for that,

Comment: is there any app to browse internal storage?

Comment: this is also not showing the packagename folders. i want to export this created file with eclipse or any application is it possible?

Comment: can you save it to external storage after saving it to internal storage?

Comment: when you saved it to internal storage you can access it in your code from there you should read and then save it to external storage.

Comment: ok in Eclipse open DDMS perspective then in it open File explorer and you can access it from there and also export it to your computer as well

Answer (score 2):

To access data/data/peckagename directory in real device you will need to have rooted device. it is for a device. In emulator  you can see using DDMS fileexplorer.BUT FOR DEVICE YOU NEED ROOTED DEVICE.

For Rooted Device :

1. go to adb directory using terminal
2. adb shell
3. su
4. cd /data/data/peckagename

Answer (score 1):

Add this permission to your Minifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: it is already added. You did not understand external storage is not an issue internal storage is and on real device I cannot find the file path.

Answer (score 1):

if this works on your emulator then do one thing. Connect your phone using cable and enable usb debugging mode. and see run your application on your phone while connected with en eclipse. And check the logcat. this should tell you what is happening.. or you can just make some toast before and after the file created that tells you whether it worked for you of not... this may look like (if (heapFile.exists()) { toast.makeText(this, "created"+path,1000).show();

I am not positive about the first solution, but the second should work!!

Comment: file is created i checked it by sending an sms to my number but i want to export this file using eclipse